# MySql counting instances of event

Tags: mysql, if-statement, case

So I have an event log that logs every 5 minutes so my logs look something like this:

```
OK
Event1
Event1
Event1
OK
Event1
OK
Event1
Event1
Event1
OK
```

In this case I'd have 3 instances of "Event1", since it had an "OK" period in between the periods when that status was returned.

Is there some decent way to handle this via mySql?   (Note, there are other statuses other than Event1 / OK that come up quite regularly)

The actual Sql structure looks something like this:

```
-Historical
    --CID //Unique Identifier, INT, AI
    --ID  //Unique Identifier for LOCATION, INT
    --LOCATION //Unique Identifier for Location, this is the site name, VarChar
    --STATUS //Pulled from Software event logger, VarChar
    --TIME //Pulled from Software event logger, DateTime
```

Comment: Do you have a timestamp or anything else on those rows?

Comment: I do have a timestamp,  My row structure will be included in an edit.

Comment: "Is there some decent way to handle this via mySql?" I'm not sure to understand what you want: Import your log into MySQL? Or somehow query the log information already present in MySQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another answer using a totally different way of doing it:-

```
SELECT MAX(@Counter) AS EventCount -- Get the max counter
FROM (SELECT @Counter:=@Counter + IF(status = 'OK' AND @PrevStatus = 1, 1, 0), -- If it is an OK record and the prev status was not an OK then add 1 to the counter
@PrevStatus:=CASE 
                WHEN status = 'OK' THEN @PrevStatus := 2 -- An OK status so save as a prev status of 2
                WHEN status != 'OK' AND @PrevStatus != 0 THEN @PrevStatus := 1 -- A non OK status but when there has been a previous OK status
                ELSE @PrevStatus:=0 -- Set the prev status to 0, ie, for a record where there is no previous OK status
            END
FROM (SELECT * FROM historical ORDER BY TimeStamp) a
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @Counter:=0, @PrevStatus := 0) b -- Initialise counter and store of prev status.
)c
```

This is using user variables. It has a subselect to get the records back in the right order, then uses a user variable to store a code for the previous status. Starts at 0 and when it finds a status of OK it sets the previous status to a 2. If it finds a status other than OK then it sets the prev status to 1, but ONLY if the prev status is not 0 (ie, it has already found a status of OK). Before storing the prev status code, if the current status is OK and the prev status code is a 1 then it adds 1 to the counter, otherwise it adds 0 (ie, adds nothing)

Then it just has a select around the outside to select the max value of the counter.

Seems to work but hardly readable!

EDIT - To cope with multiple ids

```
SELECT id, MAX(aCounter) AS EventCount -- Get the max counter for each id
FROM (SELECT id,
@PrevStatus:= IF(@Previd = id, @PrevStatus, 0), -- If the id has changed then set the store of previous status to 0
status,
@Counter:=IF(@Previd = id, @Counter + IF(status = 'OK' AND @PrevStatus = 1, 1, 0), 0) AS aCounter,  -- If it is an OK record and the prev status was not an OK and was for the same id then add 1 to the counter
@PrevStatus:=CASE 
                WHEN status = 'OK' THEN @PrevStatus := 2 -- An OK status so save as a prev status of 2
                WHEN status != 'OK' AND @PrevStatus != 0 THEN @PrevStatus := 1 -- A non OK status but when there has been a previous OK status
                ELSE @PrevStatus:=0 -- Set the prev status to 0, ie, for a record where there is no previous OK status
            END,
@Previd := id
FROM (SELECT * FROM historical ORDER BY id, TimeStamp) a
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @Counter:=0, @PrevStatus := 0, @Previd := 0) b
)c
GROUP BY id -- Group by clause to allow the selection of the max counter per id
```

Which is even less readable!

Another option, again using user variables to generate a sequence number:-

```
SELECT Sub1.id, COUNT(DISTINCT Sub1.aCounter) -- Count the number of distinct Sub1 records found for an id (without the distinct counter it would count all the recods between OK status records)
FROM (
    SELECT id,
    `TimeStamp`,
    @Counter1:=IF(@Previd1 = id, @Counter1 + 1, 0) AS aCounter, -- Counter for this status within id
    @Previd1 := id -- Store the id, used to determine if the id has changed and so whether to start the counters at 0 again
    FROM (SELECT * FROM historical WHERE status = 'OK' ORDER BY id, `TimeStamp`) a -- Just get the OK status records, in id / timestamp order
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT @Counter1:=0, @Previd1 := 0) b -- Initialise the user variables.
) Sub1
INNER JOIN (SELECT id,
    `TimeStamp`,
    @Counter2:=IF(@Previd2 = id, @Counter2 + 1, 0) AS aCounter,-- Counter for this status within id
    @Previd2 := id-- Store the id, used to determine if the id has changed and so whether to start the counters at 0 again
    FROM (SELECT * FROM historical WHERE status = 'OK' ORDER BY id, `TimeStamp`) a -- Just get the OK status records, in id / timestamp order
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT @Counter2:=0, @Previd2 := 0) b -- Initialise the user variables.
) Sub2
ON Sub1.id = Sub2.id -- Join the 2 subselects based on the id
AND Sub1.aCounter + 1 = Sub2.aCounter -- and also the counter. So Sub1 is an OK status, while Sub2 the the next OK status for that id
INNER JOIN historical Sub3 -- Join back against historical
ON Sub1.id = Sub3.id -- on the matching id
AND Sub1.`TimeStamp` < Sub3.`TimeStamp` -- and where the timestamp is greater than the timestamp in the Sub1 OK record
AND Sub2.`TimeStamp` > Sub3.`TimeStamp` -- and where the timestamp is less than the timestamp in the Sub2 OK record
GROUP BY Sub1.id -- Group by the Sub1 id
```

This is grabbing the table twice for just the status OK records, adding a sequence number each time and matching where the id matches and the sequence number on the 2nd copy is 1 greater than the first one (ie, it is finding each OK and the OK immediately following it). Then joins that against the table where the id matches and the timestamp is between the 2 OK records. Then counts the distinct occurrences of the first counter for each id.

This should be a bit more readable.

Comment: This is an awesome answer and runs like a charm, but the real question is, how would I get this to break down the list by ID?  So for example if I wanted to run this for each ID that appears in historical how would I alter that?

Comment: Let me have a play tomorrow. Probably need to add ID to the sort in the subselect (before timestamp), and also add a user var to store the prev ID, resetting @PrevStatus when ID changes.

Comment: Alright, now, just for the sake of knowing, can you explain the logic used to make these queries work?   Perhaps inline comments?   This is crazy stuff that I didn't even know MySql could do.

Comment: This is awesome, thank you so much for your help.  I'd never seen Session variables used in MySql before, so this is really helpful to me on a number of fronts.

Answer (score 0):

Quick try, and I have a feeling I am missing a far better way to do this but think this will work.

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM
(
    SELECT DISTINCT a.time, b.time
    FROM Historical a
    INNER JOIN Historical b
    ON a.time < b.time
    AND a.status = 'OK'
    AND b.status = 'OK'
    INNER JOIN Historical c
    ON a.time < c.time
    AND c.time < b.time
    AND c.status = 'Event1'
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Historical d
    ON a.time < d.time
    AND d.time < b.time
    AND d.status = 'OK'
    WHERE d.cid IS NULL
) Sub1
```

Joins the table against itself repeatedly. Alias a and b should be for OK events, with c being for any Event1 event between those dates. Alias d is looking for an OK event between a and b, and if any are found then the record is dropped in the WHERE clause.

Then use DISTINCT to get rid of the duplicates. Then count the result.

Possible it could be simplified as something like the following (although probably best to cast the dates to chars in the select if doing this)

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT CONCAT(a.time, b.time))
FROM Historical a
INNER JOIN Historical b
ON a.time < b.time
AND a.status = 'OK'
AND b.status = 'OK'
INNER JOIN Historical c
ON a.time < c.time
AND c.time < b.time
AND c.status = 'Event1'
LEFT OUTER JOIN Historical d
ON a.time < d.time
AND d.time < b.time
AND d.status = 'OK'
WHERE d.cid IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want to count, it seems, are instances of an event when the previous record is `OK`.  You identify these with a correlated subquery, and then summarize to get the numbers:

```
select status, count(*)
from (select h.*,
             (select h2.status
              from historical h2
              where h2.time < h.time
              order by h2.time desc
              limit 1
             ) as prevStatus
      from historical h
     ) h
where status <> 'OK' and (prevStatus = 'OK' or prevStatus is NULL)
group by status;
```

It is not clear which column contains the values `OK` and `Event1`.  I'm guessing it is `status`.  I also don't know what role `location` plays, but this should at least get you started.

Comment: This seems to be the best answer so far, but the performance of this query is a little worrisome to me.  86480 rows was taking somewhere in the range of 6 minutes per query.